# Is there a good way to solve an optimization problem to minimize the sum of a convex-concave fraction and a convex functions?

Tags: optimization, fractions, non-convex-optimization

I am struggling to solve the following problem: For a convex set $\mathcal{X}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, 
$$\min_{x\in\mathcal{X}}~\left\{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} + h(x)\right\},\label{prob}\tag{1}$$
where $f$ and $h$ are nonnegative convex functions w.r.t. $x$, and $g$ is a positive concave function w.r.t. $x$. I know that $f/g$ is quasiconvex, but I am not sure whether $f/g+h$ is also quasiconvex.

In more detail, for my case,
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i f_i(x),\\
g(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i,\\
h(x) &= \sum_{i=1}^n b_i f_i(x),
\end{align}
where $x_i$ represents the $i$th element of vector $x$, $a_i$ and $b_i$ are positive given constants, $f_i$ is positive and flipped-log-shaped decreasing convex function for all $i$.

---

If $h(x)$ disappeared, the problem could be solved using Dinkelbach's method, i.e., global optimal solution $x^*$ is obtained by alternatively updating until convergence as follows:
\begin{align}
y_{k+1} &\gets \frac{f(x_k)}{g(x_k)},\\
x_{k+1} &\gets \arg\max_{x\in\mathcal{X}}~\{f(x)-y_{k+1}g(x)\}.
\end{align}

---

However, I am not sure that the global solution $x^*$ to Problem \eqref{prob} can be obtained by updating in a similar way as above, i.e.,
\begin{align}
y_{k+1} &\gets \frac{f(x_k)}{g(x_k)},\\
x_{k+1} &\gets \arg\max_{x\in\mathcal{X}}~\{f(x)-y_{k+1}g(x)+h(x)\}.
\end{align}

---

To sum up, is there any way to find a global solution to Problem \eqref{prob}?
If there are some references, please recommend me. Thank you.

Comment: Is the objective function quasiconvex? What are $f$, $g$ and $h$ here?

Comment: @LinAlg I first thought that $f/g+h$ is quasiconvex, but now I am not sure that.

Comment: Did you make a typo somewhere? You wrote that $f$ is convex.

Comment: One strategy is to reconstruct the Pareto frontier of the biobjective problem with objectives $f/g$ and $h$ with the $\varepsilon$-constraint method, and derive the optimal solution from there.

Comment: @LinAlg Sorry, I made a typo. Convex is true, so I revised my question. Thank you for comments.